# torch.unique & np.unique not working on floats

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, floating-point

I have a 1D tensor `a` of float64 numbers and I want to extract unique values. After running `torch.unique(a)` or `np.unique(a)`, I get an array which has a duplicate entries on the last two positions:

```
[-14.5 -13.5 -12.5 ... 23.5  24.5  24.5]
```

When I subtract the last two elements, I get

```
-3.552713678800501e-15
```

I suppose this happens because of floating point precision. Is there some way to efficiently find unique numbers (for example within some reasonable epsilon neighborhood)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find unique elements of floating point array in numpy (with comparison using a delta value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426908/find-unique-elements-of-floating-point-array-in-numpy-with-comparison-using-a-d)

Comment: So, those functions*are working*, you just want to do something else. Anyway, the best I can come up with is sort then binary search for the closest and reject if within but it's not going to be super efficient.